# Why do web browsers don't apply the CSS :active state on activation by enter key?

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, browser, safari

Most web browsers provide keyboard shortcuts to interact with the DOM. *e.g.:*

`Tab` shifts the focus to the next focus-able element
`Alt + Tab` shifts the focus to the previous focus-able element
`Enter` activates the currently focused element

What I have now figured out is that many popular browsers (Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Internet Explorer) don't apply the CSS `:active` pseudo-class if an element gets activated by pressing the `Enter` key.

**Why is this so?**

I think it is misleading because it looks like you don't trigger the buttons; although you actually do.

Comment: I've raised an issue about a spec being not explicit enough here: https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/4787

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Aactive

According to mozilla documentation, the `active` pseudo class is related to the mouse and the tab key. But there's no mention of the Enter key.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question in any way.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [CSS Selectors specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#the-user-action-pseudo-classes-hover-act):

> The :active pseudo-class applies while an element is being activated
>   by the user. For example, between the times the user presses the mouse
>   button and releases it. [...]

So the standard explicitly says that `:active` should be applied when a user clicks on the element. There is nothing else, so this is not a problem of the browsers, it is a result of a missing standard.

Comment: It doesn't say that it should be applied when a user clicks on it. It says that it should be applied when an element is being activated. And enter does activate. Clicking is just an example.

Comment: yes, but as long as there is nothing explicitly said about anything else, no other examples are given; you can make a conclusion that clicking must work in all browsers because it is set in the standard. Meanwhile everything else is not described and is fully depending on the browser developers. If you have no request to build a house you won't build a house, right? There is no description of "activated" element

Comment: The :active pseudo-class applies while an element is **being activated** by the user.

Comment: Yes, but could you tell me please what is **being activated** and show this written in the standard? What is said here and you don't want to understand is that standard defines how the browsers work. If there is no standard - you should not expect that it will work even if you think it is obvious.

Comment: could you add to this URL the place where it says what is **being activated**? I cannot find anything like that over there

Comment: > Certain elements in HTML have an activation behavior, which means that the user can activate them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91182/discussion-between-larivact-and-smnbbrv).